# My Laptop Screen keeps flickering

Tags: windows-7, display, lenovo-laptop

I have a lenovo g530 and the screen keeps flickering on occasion.  Sometimes it is worse than others, and sometimes it doesn't seem to do it at all.  I was able to capture a [video](http://vimeo.com/10908966) of it so you could see what is happening.  I kinda wanted someone else's opinion before I open it up and check the monitor cable on the board.

- [Video Link](http://vimeo.com/10908966) (in case you missed it above)

Comment: Oh, _that_ looks like a loose cable. Woof. It'd drive me crazy.

Comment: This is most likely the cable, specifically the cable for the CFL backlighting. (Because it seems that the actual display remains active and only the backlight flickers)

Unfortunately there are two places where the cable might be loose. INSIDE the computer connecting the inverter to the power supply (motherboard), or inside the screen (usually either to the side or right below the panel itself) at the inverter board itself. You might need to take apart both the body of the laptop and the display to find the loose connector.

Comment: @crasic: someone else already mentioned this as an answer...thus converted to comment.

Comment: @studiohack no problem, I just wanted to point out that there could be two possible places where there is a loose connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Michael commented: this looks like **a cable/connection problem.**

I have something similar on one of my laptops, where I get the lines you see in the video. In my case pressing on the GPU part of the motherboard stops the flickering, but it also depends on the angle of the screen.

This makes me assume it's a **cable problem**, that's **not connecting properly**.

I wish you luck with opening it up, but if it's still got warranty, I'd sent it in... Even though you'll have to miss your laptop for three months

Comment: Well I have worked on laptops before, so its not like I don't know how to.  I just have never seen something like this before so I just wanted a second opinion.  Thanks to you both for the help.  I will let you know when I open it up if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Haha, I'm sure you do :-) But I wouldn't dare try it on my laptop. Though now it's out of warranty, I might as well give it a go too!

Comment: @Chris @Ivo did you fix it by reconnecting the cable. I have a similar problem with my Asus K61IC

Comment: Actually I never tried to open it, though I might give it a shot now that I no longer use it (on a daily basis)

Comment: @Chris @Ivo problem solved by reconnecting the display cable

Comment: Yes, I have been able to solve the issue. However it will forever be reoccurring...It's the way the frame is built to constantly torque the screws and cause them to wind themselves out. So I have to repeat this same thing every 3 months or so (I use my computer quite a bit).

Comment: Another Youtube video and discussion for K61 flickering http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z70aVekw2rs

Comment: Another Youtube video and discussion for K61 flickering http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1csIukxBnc

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my ASUS laptop. Since it gave me lots of headache, I removed back cover and remove dust on VGA chips. It solved the problem and it occurs again whenever dust accumulated on chips through ventilation hole.