# Lenovo G530 laptop screen flicker

Tags: display, lcd, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo G530 laptop that has an issue with screen flicker that is getting worse.  The computer screen will start going thru a crazy screen flicker then will stop and start again.  I have already checked cable connection to lcd on motherboard and reseated connection as someone suggested in another posting I found online that resolved issue.  I am starting to think it might be a bad inverter or screen because I have hooked up laptop to external monitor and it is running fine with no flickering happening when the flickering is occurring on laptop.  I am attaching a link to a small video I shot of the issue as it is occurring on laptop screen.

Does anyone have any further suggestions?  Bad inverter or screen?

[Screen flicker video](http://www.vimeo.com/18251788)

Answer (score 1):

Usually a flicker is caused by the inverter or the actual internal signal cable itself.  If you feel up to it, I'd crack the case and just reseat the video cable - that might fix the problem.

EDIT: Oh, hey, [look what I found](https://superuser.com/questions/130662/my-laptop-screen-keeps-flickering)! Hehehe.  (The G530 is an awful machine.  I used to do support for ThinkPads and we'd get misdirected calls for these things a lot, so I've heard the gamut - you're not the first person with this problem.)

Comment: I have already reseated the video cable connection to the motherboard which is why I was wondering if it could be the inverter causing the issue.  When I reseated the cable which was about 1 month ago, it worked fine for a while and now having same issue again, which is why I am now considering the inverter.

Comment: @Kevin - I still probably would look at replacing the cable before the inverter.  It's more likely to be the problem and probably APPRECIABLY cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

[This guy seems](http://www.whatsmykarma.com/blog/?p=495) to have found a good solution

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Flickering Problem fixed.

I have Lenovo G530. I had similar problem  for long time (more than a year).

I used to reattach the left LCD cable which would fix the problem temporarily. But the flickering would start after sometime again.

I also found out that the flickering would stop if i pressed down on the panel next to the power switch area (Not the power switch). I figured it must be the loose cable on the left of the LCD. So I put a little piece of paper & taped it right below the power switch, where there is little empty space without cables.

The idea was to push the left LCD cable & keep it firmly attached. I used a simple copy paper folded 3-4 times about 1/2 inch wide & 2 inch long. The paper is taped at the bottom of the top panel in a way that it will push down on the left LCD cable.

Since then, I haven't had flickering for a month now.
This is probably one of the most stupidest fix i had done in my life !!!

Answer (score 0):

I work at a middle school and we had five laptops with this problem. I pressed down on the panel next to the power switch and the flickering stop. I then placed the 2" folder paper on the bottom of the panel and flickering has stopped.

Thanks